# Warning: Using UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: reactjs

```
bundle.js:110595 Warning: Using UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps in strict mode is not recommended and may indicate bugs in your code. See https://reactjs.org/link/unsafe-component-lifecycles for details.

* Move data fetching code or side effects to componentDidUpdate.
* If you're updating state whenever props change, refactor your code to use memoization techniques or move it to static getDerivedStateFromProps. Learn more at: https://reactjs.org/link/derived-state

Please update the following components: **Component**
```

Comment: What is the question? You are using an outdated/unsafe method and it is warning you about it.

Comment: I'm not using any method of this name. My whole react js app is developed with functional components and I'm using useEffect hook, so please help me in this issue. My question is, how to solve this issue?